# Bootstrap: Unable to download Glyphicon Font file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, glyphicons

I'm trying to resolve an issue we're running into with Twitter Bootstrap's Glyphicons.  In our dev environments and our machines work fine.  The problem is when the client tries to view our code.  They are forced to have IE network policies that are not allowing the download of the glyphicon's font files.  I can tell this is the case because I am checking out the network tab in the IE debugger and it shows it can't download the font file.  The IE Policy is "Allow font Downloads."  Having them change their policies is probably a no go.  I was wondering if there are any alternatives besides somehow extracting the images and using img tags instead.  If the latter is the only solution, does anyone have the best way to accomplish this?  The thing about bootstrap is we're able to change size/color of the glyphicons easily, as well as ease of js modification via changing css classes.

Here is how we import them in our app:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

The actual font tiles are in the resources/fonts.  css files are in resources/css.  We know they are there since all other environments are able to see the icons.

IE Network Message:

```
Key     Value
Request         GET /appName/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot? HTTP/1.1
```

Usage of glyphicons:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
```

Comment: Probably a no-go? I'd start there before I'd jump through a bunch of hoops.

Comment: You could revert to Bootstrap 2's method of using icon sprites, but they aren't resizable or colorable.

Comment: Had a similar problem. First due to security settings in IE it won't let you view the files locally since it's going outside your network for all sorts of libraries. Can the client view your project when uploaded to a web server and given the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the responses.  It seems that the only way around this was in fact to use images of my own.  I was able to minimize code impact by just replacing the bootstrap css :before that was inserting the glyphicon characters and just replace that with styling on the background of the span element using images that someone posted online of the glyphs.  If anyone is interested for each glyph I was using I replaced the commented out code below with the inserted class and this seems to solve my issue.

```
.glyphicon-plus-sign{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('../images/glyphicons_190_circle_plus.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
/*.glyphicon-plus-sign:before {
  content: "\e081";
}*/
```